# Stacking Cactus + PocketWizard?

Tags: off-camera-flash, hotshoe, light-meter, pocket-wizard, cactus

I'm interested in picking up a Sekonic L-758, and while PocketWizard triggering sounds interesting, I don't want to have to buy the light meter AND two PocketWizards to try it out.

It occurred to me that I might only need to buy one PocketWizard, if I use my existing Cactus transceivers.

I've created a diagram to explain how I'm imagining this...

Basically, the Cactus radios will trigger the flash when my camera takes a picture, but the PocketWizard radios will communicate for taking meter readings. The hotshoe stacking will look a little funny, but it should work, right?

[image: I put something together in OmniGraffle that hopefully helps get my point across.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does work!

I put the Cactus receiver on top of the PocketWizard (using the Plus IV) and the Flash on top of the receiver. The meter has has its own PocketWizard transmitter, and the camera has its own Cactus transmitter.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work. Different frequencies, different channels, different brands.

Comment: I'm not trying to trigger one with the other, simply getting them both to trigger the same flash, via a hotshoe.